# Ipad app behave strangely on my wrapped HTML

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ipad

I have a hidden div which get slide effect from right to left by using jquery. In css I have used this code. '#sitemap' is the id of the hidden div. It is working well in all browsers.

```
#siteMap {
  width:80%;
  position:fixed;
  right:-80%;
  top:0px;
  display:block;
  color:#FFF;
  z-index:2;
  background:#fff;
  overflow:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height:100%;

 }
```

You can see in the css code that the box get start from top of the window (top:0px). It is acting same in browser, but when I tried to wrap it in IOS and play it on Ipad the div open not from the top, rather it is giving some space from top. Please see the attached image. But when I again click somewhere on the page it move to the top and showing at the top. Any idea why it is acting so strangely. Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
#siteMap {
  width:80%;
  position:fixed;
  right:-80%;
  top:0px !important; // CHANGE THIS
  display:block;
  color:#FFF;
  z-index:2;
  background:#fff;
  overflow:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height:100%;

 }
```

oh, and for iOS Browser, the overflow is -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;